# Simultaneously Bulk Load to Multiple HBase Tables from MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Similar to `MultiTableOutputFormat` where you can write to Multiple HBase tables using `put`. Is there an inbuilt way to generate multiple `HFile`s without looping through the input multiple times?

Comment: You need to you Hbase Bulk loading feature(generating Hbase) and load into 2 Hbase tables. Am I right?

Comment: @Ramzy, yes.. thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://tech.adroll.com/blog/data/2014/07/15/multi-table-bulk-import.html) is the nearest to your requirement. They have given the code too to handle multiple output format. One more [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/21724).Hope it helps

Comment: I have looked at this before but didnt want to add new `MultiHFileOutputFormat` which will require to keep up with changes in original `HFileOutputFormat`.. which is why I was asking for inbuilt way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience and it may vary by what version of Hadoop you run.

First, you probably don't want to try to write out multiple HFiles at one time. The HFileOutputFormat doesn't honor certain settings that is set by the MultipleOutputs utility. It may work, it may not depending on what version of Hadoop and how you have your column families named.

What you can do is output KeyValues sequence files via MutlipleOutputs. Use one sequence file for each column family. Then, for each sequence file use M/R to do an identity Map over the sequence file and use the HFileOutputFormat.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Using Spark module from page :
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/admin_hbase_import.html#concept_asc_ctz_wp